# Why does my cursor work then break in SQL

Tags: sql-server

This is my code. It runs through a table that has years that a company was founded in and it is supposed to pull each year from the row one by one and print it.

```
  DECLARE @Yearfounded int
--Now I am going to start work on the cursor

DECLARE @YearsCursor CURSOR 
Select [YEar] From dbo.YearsRunning

OPEN YearsCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM YearsCursor into @Yearfounded

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

Begin

Print @Yearfounded

Fetch Next From YearsCursor into @Yearfounded

End

Close YearsCursor
Deallocate YearsCursor
```

This is the error I am getting

> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 A cursor with the name
>   'YearsCursor' does not exist. Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 A
>   cursor with the name 'YearsCursor' does not exist. Msg 16916, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 26 A cursor with the name 'YearsCursor' does not
>   exist. Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 27 A cursor with the name
>   'YearsCursor' does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use cursor variable name:

```
DECLARE @YearsCursor CURSOR  
SET @YearsCursor  =CURSOR FOR  Select  Select [YEar] From dbo.YearsRunning
```

Or check syntax cursor
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

```
  DECLARE @Yearfounded int
--Now I am going to start work on the cursor

DECLARE YearsCursor CURSOR FOR Select [YEar] From dbo.YearsRunning

OPEN YearsCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM YearsCursor into @Yearfounded

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

Begin

Print @Yearfounded

Fetch Next From YearsCursor into @Yearfounded

End

Close YearsCursor
Deallocate YearsCursor
```

Comment: See difference in cursor definition

Answer (score 0):

define the cursor like this

DECLARE YearsCursor CURSOR for

Answer (score -1):

```
 DECLARE @Yearfounded int
--Now I am going to start work on the cursor

DECLARE @YearsCursor CURSOR 
Select [YEar] From dbo.YearsRunning

    OPEN @YearsCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM YearsCursor into @Yearfounded

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

Begin

Print @Yearfounded

Fetch Next From YearsCursor into @Yearfounded

End

Close @YearsCursor
Deallocate @YearsCursor
```

you forgot to add `@` while opening closing and deallocating the cursor

Comment: I just rectified all of the problems that you mentioned however I am still getting the same errors